# Storage of value types and reference types in .net

Tags: c#, .net

In .net, the **value types** are stored on **stack** where as **reference types** are stored on **managed heap**. What is the reason for this one? Is it not possible to exchange their storage locations?

Comment: _"the value types are stored on stack where as reference types are stored on managed heap."_ This is a huge fallacy - value types are equally able to be stored in the heap (via boxing or embedded in a reference type), or could be stored in a register. And what about references? (nether reference type nor value type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The stack is an implementation detail.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one)  The important thing is the reference/value distinction.

> Is it not possible to exchange their storage locations?

It's very easy to store value types on the heap.

```
class ReferenceInt
{
    public int Field;
}

ReferenceInt n = new ReferenceInt();
// n.Field is now stored on the heap.
```

Comment: @Dan.. in the above example `n.Field` is reference type right!! So it  will store on heap, but in above statement you said that **easy to store value types on heap**... two types are storing in heap only. two solutions sounds like same... can you please explain.

Comment: No, `n.Field` is an `int`, which is a value type.

Comment: But the n.Field value type would be **embedded** in the ReferenceInt type, which is stored in the heap. So n.Field would not be on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

[These](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one) brilliant [articles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two) by Eric Lippert should tell you what you need to know. To sum up: don't worry about it.